# Delete Report From Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way of deleting a report from Acumatica?
I have a series of test reports when I look at my report designer - half of which I don't need anymore

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY at your own RISK =)**

I saw a table UserReport having the information about the reports, also i found a folder under sites folder with report files..

You can try deleting the entry from table UserReport which matches your report name and the company.

After that if the report file is inside the folder YOURSITE\ReportsCustomized you can delete that too.

Comment: Hybridzz is correct.   Reports saved directly from the report designer are stored in the database in the "UserReport" table.   That's keyed by ReportFileName / Version.     Reports can also be uploaded to the server directly and stored in the "ReportsCustomized" folder but you won't find anything there unless you manually put it there.    Remember to remove any from the sitemap first before clearing them from the UserReport table

Comment: Thanks guys, does that mean that the acumatica UI doesn't allow you to delete anything?

Comment: I didnt see any UI option to delete. May be we will wait for such an answer.

Comment: @Gaga Correct, Acumatica UI doesn't have such deletion features, nor the Report Designer. You will have to go into the folder structure for the instance.